# Possible for adwords conversion to be combination of pages instead of just 1 URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Thank you in advance for your help.

We would like to measure a conversion within adwords (or even as an analytics goal) for when a customer visits a combination of pages (the order of the pages visited doesnt matter).

We use adwords conversion optimizer, so adwords absolutely must receive the data for it to optimize bids based on the correct data.

For example, if a person visits BOTH of these pages, in any order, then adwords measures it as a conversion:

http://www.mysite.org/category_s/45.htm

http://www.mysite.org/category_s/90.htm

Right now within google adwords you can only measure a conversion when a customer visits ONE page, not a combination of pages.

For us it is very important for the potential customer to visit BOTH pages for for the conversion to be valuable.

We have attempted doing this with a google anayltics goal funnel (which we have indeed linked to our adwords account), but the so called "required step" is not actually required to measure the conversion. It is measured whether or not the other page is visited, and counted as a conversion.

Is this possible? Modify the adwords conversion tracking code? Is it possible to setup as an analytics "Event" goal?

Thank you for your help!

GW

Answer (score 0):

Create a goal for url one. Create a goal for url two. Create a custom segment for visitors that have met both goals.

And yes, it's  possible to have event based goals, I just don't see how this would solve your problem.

Comment: We use adwords conversion optimizer, so adwords absolutely must receive the data for it to optimize bids based on the correct data.  Thanks again for your help.